# What's wrong with this PHP code?? Array key resets automatically

Tags: php, arrays

I am facing this weird error, I get the value of 'email' from POST. I var_dump() to make sure I got the value and here's the output of var_dump:

```
string(255) "array(7) { ["no"]=> bool(false) ["email"]=> string(21) "munir.ehmad@gmail.com" }
```

But in the following code if I uncomment the response line the if condition gets executed (i.e. if expression returns true) which shouldn't be happening. And if I comment the $this->response part, the if condition won't execute and else part would... :S

The code is below, I've been wasting hours on this and still no clue what's happening right now. Please help!

P.S: I either want to have user's email or no, or both but he should give me at-least one of them.

---

**Code:**

```
$user['no']     = $this->post('no');
$user['email']  = $this->post('email');

var_dump($user);

if ( !$user['no'] && !$user['email'] )
{
  echo 'Error occured';
  //$this->response( array('msg'=>'Mobile No or Email must be provided'), 400);
  return;
}
else
  echo 'not error';

exit();
```

**EDIT: Any mercenary who believes this is not happening IRL Right now is invited to view my desktop on skype while I do his bidding to fix the error. (id: munir.ehmad)**

Comment: What does `$this->response()` do? Is that some framework you are using?

Comment: You want to check `!$user['no'] || !$user['email']` (or) - otherwise it makes not much sense.

Comment: @knittl yes, it just sends out JSON response with specified HTTP code.

Comment: @Quasdunk I Want to have either user's no or email, if he doesn't provide both of them, I should return error. Makes sense now? :)

Comment: You should use isset() to check to see if a key is set in an array.

Comment: @max_ $this->post() functions return false if the key doesn't exists which is ok.

Comment: If this is the case you are sending invalid JSON: `Error occured{'msg':'Mobile No or Email must be provided'}`

Comment: @knittl the main problem is it shouldn't execute the code inside if at all.

Comment: Comeone someone should see it for himself, add me on skype and help :(

Answer (score 2):

A php array would var_dump as

```
array(7) { 
       ["no"]=> bool(false) 
       ["email"]=> string(21) "munir.ehmad@gmail.com" 
           }
```

your "array" var_dumps as a **string** with that content. If that is the exact output of your var_dump, then it would seem you have a string. Something must be happening to that var.

I believe that if you try and use a string as an array, you will get unexpected results, presumably like above.

Start debugging like so:

Make a NEW script, with nothing but the part that bothers you.

```
$user = array();
$user['no']     = false;
$user['email']  = "someemail@email.com";

var_dump($user);

if ( !$user['no'] && !$user['email'] )
{
  echo 'Error occured';
}else{
  echo 'not error';
}
```

Run this script. Verify that it does what you expect it does. If it doesn't, either change your code or your expectations.
Try to run it with a POST, adding the POST values directly to the $user array (using `$user = $_POST;` for example). Run the script again. Verify. Use the `$this->post` variable next time. etc.

Go on until you have a script that behaves in a way you cannot explain. Come back and post that script.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that gives me some direction let me fiddle with it.

Comment: I am sorry that's not the case. :/

Comment: Either it is the case, or you should update your question. The var dump would not produce that result if it would not be a string. My suggestion: make a script that should work. Add your parts piece by piece, and find out the bug. I'll give you an example

Comment: The problem was with REST Client

Answer (score 0):

This does not have anything to do with the line you commented. It cannot. (Except if it results in a new request, e.g. via `header(Location: ...)`)

Let's take a look at your var_dump.
`$user['no']` is `false`. So `!$user['no']` is `true`.
However, `$user['email']`is `munir.ehmad@gmail.com` and `!$user['email']` is `false`. Are you sure that you have a `&&` (and) in your code and not a `||` (or)?

(To me, `||` would make actually more sense.)

Comment: Exactly and that's the problem

Comment: Yes I am sure because I either want to have user's email or no or both but he should give me at-least one of them

Comment: So are you absolutely sure the `this->response` doesn't trigger a page refresh or anything?

Comment: No no it doesn't. It only does this:

Comment: header('HTTP/1.1: ' . $http_code);
    header('Status: ' . $http_code);
    header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($output));

    exit($output);

Comment: So you're sending out a `400 Bad Request`?

Comment: Exaclty, but id doesn't matter right? If I uncomment I get this:

object(stdClass)#19 (1) { ["msg"]=> string(35) "Mobile No or Email must be provided" }

Comment: I don't understand your `response()`. Why are you putting in an array (`array('msg'=>'Mobile No or Email must be provided')`) and try to print it using `exit`? How is that supposed to work? (I guess that's why you get some weirdly casting BTW.) Are you sure you don't want to `echo $output['msg']`? What's up with all the exiting anyway?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5736/discussion-between-blackdivine-and-middus)

Answer (score 0):

try use isset or empty function.

```
if ( !empty($user['no']) && !empty($user['email']) ) {
   ....
   ....
}
```

Comment: tried, if ( empty($user['no']) && empty($user['email']) ), still same ____

Comment: if you can ensure that $_POST variable is not empty as var_dump result, why you don't try to use: $user['no'] = $_POST["no"]; and $user['email']  = $_POST["email"];

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the Negatives, the problem was in [REST Client](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restclient) I was using.

Did a manual CURL POST from client-side with same Parameters and it works flawlessly.